# IIS Windows Authentication

Tags: windows, authentication, iis, single-sign-on

There is a third-party Systems, Its authentication is through IIS Windows Authentication(Integration AD).
Now,I want to realize single signon with sharepoint. I know Sharepoint 2010 has a SSS services
and I can config it. My Question : Even though I can get the account and password, how can I give them to third-party System, then sign on the System's specified web pages.